# Echo Device Token Using Php

Tags: php, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

How can I echo the `$token` value in this `api.php` file? My app uses push notifications and thusly the `$token` variable in this API file gets set to the 64 character `device token` that each user gets when the app is downloaded. So far the token successfully gets posted to the database, I just need to be able to echo it out. My ultimate goal is to set $token to a global variable and pass it to a new file to use in additional php statements. The echo is just so I can make sure we can explicitly get it first.

```
 <?php


// This is the server API for the PushChat iPhone app. To use the API, the app
// sends an HTTP POST request to our URL. The POST data contains a field "cmd"
// that indicates what API command should be executed.

try 
{
// Are we running in development or production mode? You can easily switch
// between these two in the Apache VirtualHost configuration.
if (!defined('APPLICATION_ENV'))
    define('APPLICATION_ENV', getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'); // was development

// In development mode, we show all errors because we obviously want to 
// know about them. We don't do this in production mode because that might
// expose critical details of our app or our database. Critical PHP errors
// will still be logged in the PHP and Apache error logs, so it's always
// a good idea to keep an eye on them.
if (APPLICATION_ENV == 'development')
{
    error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
    ini_set('display_errors', 'on');

}
else
{
    error_reporting(0);
    ini_set('display_errors', 'off');
}

// Load the config file. I prefer to keep all configuration settings in a
// separate file so you don't have to mess around in the main code if you
// just want to change some settings.
require_once 'api_config.php';
$config = $config[APPLICATION_ENV];

// In development mode, we fake a delay that makes testing more realistic.
// You're probably running this on a fast local server but in production
// mode people will be using it on a mobile device over a slow connection.
if (APPLICATION_ENV == 'development')
    sleep(0);
//here
// To keep the code clean, I put the API into its own class. Create an
// instance of that class and let it handle the request.

$api = new API($config);
$api->handleCommand();

echo "OK" . PHP_EOL;

}
catch (Exception $e)
{
// The code throws an exception when something goes horribly wrong; e.g.
// no connection to the database could be made. In development mode, we
// show these exception messages. In production mode, we simply return a
// "500 Server Error" message.

if (APPLICATION_ENV == 'development')
    var_dump($e);
else
    exitWithHttpError(500);

}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function exitWithHttpError($error_code, $message = '')
{
//here 
switch ($error_code)
{
    case 400: header("HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request"); break;
    case 403: header("HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden"); break;
    case 404: header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"); break;
    case 500: header("HTTP/1.0 500 Server Error"); break;
}
//here
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

if ($message != '')
    header('X-Error-Description: ' . $message);
//here
/*exit;*/
}

function isValidUtf8String($string, $maxLength, $allowNewlines = false)
{

if (empty($string) || strlen($string) > $maxLength)
    return false;

if (mb_check_encoding($string, 'UTF-8') === false)
    return false;

// Don't allow control characters, except possibly newlines 
for ($t = 0; $t < strlen($string); $t++)
{
    $ord = ord($string{$t});

    if ($allowNewlines && ($ord == 10 || $ord == 13))
        continue;

    if ($ord < 32)
        return false;
}

return true;
}

function truncateUtf8($string, $maxLength)
{
$origString = $string;
$origLength = $maxLength;

while (strlen($string) > $origLength)
{
    $string = mb_substr($origString, 0, $maxLength, 'utf-8');
    $maxLength--;
}

return $string;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//here new: try to echo something here

class API
{
// Because the payload only allows for 256 bytes and there is some overhead
// we limit the message text to 190 characters.
const MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH = 190;

private $pdo;

function __construct($config)
{
    // Create a connection to the database.
    $this->pdo = new PDO(
        'mysql:host=' . $config['db']['host'] . ';dbname=' . $config['db']['dbname'], 
        $config['db']['username'], 
        $config['db']['password'],
        array());

    // If there is an error executing database queries, we want PDO to
    // throw an exception. Our exception handler will then exit the script
    // with a "500 Server Error" message.
    $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // We want the database to handle all strings as UTF-8.
    $this->pdo->query('SET NAMES utf8');
}

function handleCommand()
{

    // Figure out which command the client sent and let the corresponding
    // method handle it. If the command is unknown, then exit with an error
    // message.
    if (isset($_POST['cmd']))
    {
        switch (trim($_POST['cmd']))
        {
            case 'join': $this->handleJoin(); return;
            case 'leave': $this->handleLeave(); return;
            case 'update': $this->handleUpdate(); return;
            case 'message': $this->handleMessage(); return;
        }
    }

    exitWithHttpError(400, 'Unknown command');
}

// The "join" API command registers a user to receive notifications that
// are sent in a specific "chat room". Each chat room is identified by a
// secret code. All the users who register with the same secret code can
// see each other's messages.
//
// This command takes the following POST parameters:
//
// - user_Id:  A unique identifier. Must be a string of 40 hexadecimal characters.
// - token: The device's device token. Must be a string of 64 hexadecimal
//          characters, or "0" if no token is available yet.
// - name:  The nickname of the user. Must be a UTF-8 string of maximum 255
//          bytes. Only the first 20 bytes are actually shown in the push 
//          notifications.
// - code:  The secret code that identifies the chat room. Must be a UTF-8
//          string of maximum 255 bytes.
//


function handleJoin()
{

    //function getUserId;
    global $userId;
    $userId = $this->getUserId();
    $token = $this->getDeviceToken(true);
    $name = $this->getString('name', 255);
    $code = $this->getString('code', 255);

    // When the client sends a "join" command, we add a new record to the
    // active_users table. We identify the client by the user_id that it
    // provides. When the client sends a "leave" command, we delete its
    // record from the active_users table.

    // It is theoretically possible that a client sends a "join" command
    // while its user_id is still present in active_users (because it did not
    // send a "leave" command). In that case, we simply remove the old
    // record first and then insert the new one.

    $this->pdo->beginTransaction();

    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM active_users WHERE user_Id = ?');
    $stmt->execute(array($userId));

    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO active_users (user_Id, device_token, nickname, secret_code, ip_address) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
    $stmt->execute(array($userId, $token, $name, $code, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));

    $this->pdo->commit();

}

// The "leave" API command removes a user from a chat room. That user will
// no longer receive push notifications for messages sent to that room.
//
// This command takes the following POST parameters:
//
// - user_id: A unique identifier. Must be a string of 40 hexadecimal characters.
//
function handleLeave()
{
    $userId = $this->getUserId();
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM active_users WHERE user_Id = ?');
    $stmt->execute(array($userId));
}

// The "update" API command gives a user a new device token.
//
// This command takes the following POST parameters:
//
// - user_id:  A unique identifier. Must be a string of 40 hexadecimal characters.
// - token: The device's device token. Must be a string of 64 hexadecimal
//          characters.
//
function handleUpdate()
{
    $userId = $this->getUserId();
    $token = $this->getDeviceToken(false);
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('UPDATE active_users SET device_token = ? WHERE user_Id = ?');
    $stmt->execute(array($token, $userId));

}

// The "message" API command sends a message to all users who are registered
// with the same secret code as the sender of the message.
//
// This command takes the following POST parameters:
//
// - user_id: A unique identifier. Must be a string of 40 hexadecimal characters.
// - text: The message text. Must be a UTF-8 string of maximum 190 bytes.
//
function handleMessage()
{
    $userId = $this->getUserId();
    /*$text = $this->getString('text', self::MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH, true);*/

    // First, we get the record for the sender of the message from the
    // active_users table. That gives us the nickname, device token, and
    // secret code for that user.

    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM active_users WHERE user_Id = ? LIMIT 1');
    $stmt->execute(array($userId));
    $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    if ($user !== false)
    {
        // Put the sender's name and the message text into the JSON payload
        // for the push notification.
        $payload = $this->makePayload($user->nickname/*, $text*/);

        // Find the device tokens for all other users who are registered
        // for this secret code. We exclude the device token of the sender
        // of the message, so he will not get a push notification. We also
        // exclude users who have not submitted a valid device token yet.
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT device_token FROM active_users WHERE secret_code = ? AND device_token <> ? AND device_token <> '0'");
        $stmt->execute(array($user->secret_code, $user->device_token));
        $tokens = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

        // Send out a push notification to each of these devices.
        foreach ($tokens as $token)
        {
            $this->addPushNotification($token, $payload);
        }
    }
}

// Retrieves the user identifier from the POST data. If the user_id does not
// appear to be valid, the script exits with an error message.
function getUserId()
{   
    if (!isset($_POST['user_id']))
        exitWithHttpError(400, 'Missing user_id');

    $userId = trim(urldecode($_POST['user_id']));
    if (!$this->isValidUserId($userId))
        exitWithHttpError(400, 'Invalid user_id');

    return $userId;
}

// Checks whether the format of the user identifier is correct (40 hex
// characters or 32 for the simulator).
function isValidUserId($userId)
{
    if (strlen($userId) != 40 && strlen($userId) != 32)  // 32 for simulator
        return false;

    if (preg_match("/^[0-9a-fA-F]+$/", $userId) == 0)
        return false;

    return true;
}

// Retrieves the device token from the POST data. If the token does not
// appear to be valid, the script exits with an error message.
function getDeviceToken($mayBeEmpty = false)
{
    if (!isset($_POST['token']))
        exitWithHttpError(400, 'Missing device token');

    $token = trim($_POST['token']);

    // The "join" command allows a token value of "0" to be specified,
    // which is necessary in case the client did not yet obtain a device
    // token at that point. We allow such clients to join, but they will
    // not receive any notifications until they provide a valid token
    // using the "update" command.
    if ($mayBeEmpty && $token == "0")
        return $token;

    if (!$this->isValidDeviceToken($token))
        exitWithHttpError(400, 'Invalid device token');

    return $token; 

}

// Checks whether the format of the device token is correct (64 hexadecimal
// characters). Note: we have no means to verify whether the device token
// was really issued by APNS and corresponds to an actual device.
function isValidDeviceToken($deviceToken)
{
    if (strlen($deviceToken) != 64)
        return false;

    if (preg_match("/^[0-9a-fA-F]{64}$/", $deviceToken) == 0)
        return false;

    return true;
}

// Looks in the POST data for a field with the given name. If the field
// is not a valid UTF-8 string, or it is too long, the script exits with
// an error message.
function getString($name, $maxLength, $allowNewlines = false)
{
    if (!isset($_POST[$name]))
        exitWithHttpError(400, "Missing $name");

    $string = trim($_POST[$name]);
    if (!isValidUtf8String($string, $maxLength, $allowNewlines))
        exitWithHttpError(400, "Invalid $name");

    return $string;
}

// Creates the JSON payload for the push notification message. The "alert"
// text has the following format: "sender_name: message_text". Recipients
// can obtain the name of the sender by parsing the alert text up to the
// first colon followed by a space.
function makePayload($senderName, $text)
{
    // Convert the nickname of the sender to JSON and truncate to a maximum
    // length of 20 bytes (which may be less than 20 characters).
    $nameJson = $this->jsonEncode($senderName);
    $nameJson = truncateUtf8($nameJson, 20);

    // Convert and truncate the message text
    $textJson = $this->jsonEncode($text);
    $textJson = truncateUtf8($textJson, self::MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH);

    // Combine everything into a JSON string
    $payload = '{"aps":{"alert":"' . $nameJson . ': Just zapped a live picture of you. Tap this message to zap them back. ' . $textJson . '","sound":"beep.caf"}}';
    return $payload;
}

// We don't use PHP's built-in json_encode() function because it converts
// UTF-8 characters to \uxxxx. That eats up 6 characters in the payload for
// no good reason, as JSON already supports UTF-8 just fine.
function jsonEncode($text)
{
    static $from = array("\\", "/", "\n", "\t", "\r", "\b", "\f", '"');
    static $to = array('\\\\', '\\/', '\\n', '\\t', '\\r', '\\b', '\\f', '\"');
    return str_replace($from, $to, $text);
}

// Adds a push notification to the push queue. The notification will not
// be sent immediately. The server runs a separate script, push.php, which 
// periodically checks for new entries in this database table and sends
// them to the APNS servers.
function addPushNotification($deviceToken, $payload)
{
    // Payloads have a maximum size of 256 bytes. If the payload is too
    // large (which shouldn't happen), we won't send this notification.
    if (strlen($payload) <= 256)
    {
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO push_queue (device_token, payload, time_queued) VALUES (?, ?, NOW())');
        $stmt->execute(array($deviceToken, $payload));
    }

}
 }

?>
```

The above file has 4 main commands used from in the app via AFNetworking `join, update, leave, message`.

**UPDATE**

When my users download the app, they inately register for device tokens like this

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{

NSString* newToken = [deviceToken description];
newToken = [newToken stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
newToken = [newToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

NSLog(@"My token is: %@", newToken);

}
```

Notice the NSLog statement that echoes out the token in the NSLog like this

[image]

This is an example method that uses `objective c` `j son` and `AFNetworking` framework to post the token (and other paramaters) to the database using an NSDictionary. This is the update method. Its php counterpart can be found in the `api.php` file above.

```
- (void)postUpdateRequest
{
UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController*)_window.rootViewController;
ChatViewController *chatViewController = (ChatViewController*)[navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

DataModel *dataModel = chatViewController.dataModel;

NSDictionary *params = @{@"cmd":@"update",
                         @"user_id":[dataModel userId],
                         @"token":[dataModel deviceToken]};

AFHTTPClient *client = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ServerApiURL]];
[client
 postPath:@"/api.php"
 parameters:params
 success:nil failure:nil];
}
```

Lastly, notice how the device token gets inserted in the database.

[image]

**Goal** I simply want to add an `echo` statement to the php file above that will successfully echo out the device token. I am testing the user `icey` whose info can now successfully post to the database. The thing is; no matter where I put the echo statement, nothing shows up or I get a warning.

Comment: What's not working with it then?

Comment: I', not sure where to properly put the echo statement. Because of I'm not yet sure how to even write a proper statement with the `$token` value. Also, because there are so many `$_POST enabled` functions in the file, I'm not sure if I have to open the file in a web browser and keep refreshing to see the successful hypothetical statement or not.

Comment: A whole bunch of things are being posted, the device token included. I just want to make sure I can actually echo out the token in the browser.

Comment: pls explain more, i am not getting what you exactly want.   ----> My ultimate goal is to set $token to a global variable and pass it to a new file to use in additional php statements.----->>  include that file and call that function, make object of that class, you can call statically that function, like : API::getDeviceToken(true)

Comment: For now I just tried putting `echo "$token"` in the `handleJoin` method. Because the `handleJoin` method already facilitates retrieving the user device tokens, posting it to the database, I figured if i put `echo "$token"` in the same block, it should work when that method is called from the app, but so far, when I open the php file in browser after calling `handleJoin` nothing shows up

Comment: Can you post some code so I can see what that would look like @monty?

Comment: I take a example : You have class A and some function is written in class A like a1, a2,a3. You have another class B. you want to use function of A class in B class. You can do it using two ways. Either create object or call function statically, in both case you have to include Class A in your B file. Example : $aobj = new A(); $afun = $aobj->a1(); -----OR-----> $afun = A::a1();

Comment: right now the 4 functions I mentioned `update, join, message, leave` are located in the `api.php` file, under the `try` block in a class called `API`. Here are the statements used for that: `$api = new API($config);
 $api->handleCommand();` these statements are used in lined 49, 50 above...

Comment: Thank you @monty for the info on objects. That will help me from here on as I extend the above file's data into other files however, I still need to know how to simply echo the `$token` variable. Right now I just want to echo it out in google chrome when I point my browser to `api.php`. I am not sure where to put the exact statement or how to yield the desired effect. Have you any ideas?

Comment: I've tried `echo "$token"` in multiple spots in the above file but nothing shows in the browser when I refresh

Comment: The `$token` variable simply holds the 64 character device token string that each user gets when they download the app. I've updated the question too with more info

Comment: @Program1 $token is coming from $_POST. First you have to set it, then you can call it like echo $this->getDeviceToken(true); You have to write this code in your API constructor. Whenever this file load it will echo $token on browser.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102874/discussion-between-program1-and-monty).

Comment: Hey @Monty thanks for the help. Whats the status on the github file?